# Html2canvas not render downloaded image properly

Tags: javascript, css, html2canvas

I have a requirement to convert radial progress to png and when I try to download the image it show the progress filled as full not partial. The document says transform has limited support and not much idea about which features are supported. It their workaround to fix this?

[image: Downloaded image]

Actual HTML render

[image]

Comment: Is it svg image??

Comment: it's a png @SaurabhAgrawal